# Select start and end dates for changing values in SQL

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a database with accounts and historical status changes

select Date, Account, OldStatus, NewStatus from HistoricalCodes
order by Account, Date

| Date | Account | OldStatus | NewStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 12345 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-10-01 | 12345 | 2 | 3 |
| 2020-11-01 | 12345 | 3 | 2 |
| 2020-12-01 | 12345 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | 54321 | 2 | 3 |
| 2020-09-01 | 54321 | 3 | 2 |
| 2020-12-01 | 54321 | 2 | 3 |

For every account I need to determine Start Date and End Date when Status = 2. An additional challenge is that the status can change back and forth multiple times. Is there a way in SQL to create something like this for at least first two timeframes when account was in 2? Any ideas?

| Account | StartDt_1 | EndDt_1 | StartDt_2 | EndDt_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-10-01 | 2020-11-01 | 2020-12-01 |
| 54321 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-12-01 |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest putting this information in separate rows:

```
select t.*
from (select account, date as startdate,
             lead(date) over (partition by account order by date) as enddate
      from t
     ) t
where newstatus = 2;
```

This produces a separate row for each period when an account has a status of `2`.  This is better than putting the dates in separate pairs of columns, because you do not need to know the maximum number of periods of status = 2 when you write the query.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed maximum of status changes per account, you can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select account,
    max(case when rn = 1 then      date end) as start_dt1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then lead_date end) as end_dt1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then      date end) as start_dt2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then lead_date end) as end_dt2
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by account, newstatus order by date) as rn,
        lead(date) over(partition by account order by date) as lead_date
    from mytable t
) t
where newstatus = 2
group by account
```

You can extend the `select` clause with more conditional expressions to handle more possible ranges per account.